# How can I only get the image url of category in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, imageurl

I am using [Taxonomy Thumbnail](https://wordpress.org/plugins/sf-taxonomy-thumbnail/) plugin to display category thumbnail, the plugin is working fine but I just want to get the url of image so that I can display it as a background image.

I have tried the following code but still it gives this format:

```
<img width="1024" height="618" src="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/Kathmandu-lumbini.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail" alt="kathmandu Pokhara Lumbini tour" srcset="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/Kathmandu-lumbini.jpg 1024w, https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/Kathmandu-lumbini-300x181.jpg 300w, https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/Kathmandu-lumbini-768x464.jpg 768w" sizes="(max-width: 1024px) 100vw, 1024px">
```

```
$background = wp_get_attachment_url(the_term_thumbnail( $term_taxonomy_id, $size = 'post-thumbnail', $attr = '' ));
```

My expected output would be

```
https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/Kathmandu-lumbini.jpg
```

Comment: check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450108/regular-expression-to-extract-src-attribute-from-img-tag

Comment: If you check the plugin code, in `inc/template-tags.php` there is a function `get_term_thumbnail_id`. Pass the term id to that, then you will get the thumbnail id back. You can then use that with `wp_get_attachment_url`.

Comment: @misorude Yes, I tried that but that does not give any data.

Comment: It should, if you give it a correct term id, for a term that has such a thumbnail set. If you are sure the ID is correct, I’d check the database to see if the meta data entry this function is looking for actually exists.

Comment: @misorude the term id refers to what?

Comment: The id of your taxonomy term of course.

Comment: @misorude. it worked. You should add this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

From this post [Regular Expression to extract src attribute from img tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450108/regular-expression-to-extract-src-attribute-from-img-tag) you can do it using preg_match:

```
preg_match('/src\s*=\s*"(.+?)"/', $background, $matches);
$background_url = $matches[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check the plugin code, in `inc/template-tags.php there` is a function `get_term_thumbnail_id`.

Pass the taxonomy term id to that, then you will get the thumbnail id back. You can then use that with `wp_get_attachment_url`.